# How to fix "reached end of file while parsing"

Tags: java, arrays, loops, class

I am writing a program to find and display the student with the highest GPA, as well as the student with the lowest GPA out of a class with 4 attributes (first name, last name, age, GPA).

The output for my code results in "build successful," but the parsing error still shows up and there isn't the proper output information.

```
public class app      
{
 public static void main(String args[ ])
 {
 student st1 = new student("Rebecca", "Collins", 22, 3.3);
 student st2 = new student("Alex", "White", 19, 2.8);
 student st3 = new student("Jordan", "Anderson", 22, 3.1);

 student[ ] studentArray = new student[3];

 studentArray[0] = st1;
 studentArray[1] = st2;
 studentArray[2] = st3;

     var maxStudent = studentArray[0];

// Start at 1 because we assumed the first student in the array
// has the current max.
//
for (int i = 1; i < studentArray.length; i++)
 {
    // If the current student has a GPA higher than the student
    // with the current max, make the current student the student
    // with the current max.
    // 
    if(studentArray[i].gpa > maxStudent.getGpa())
    {

     boolean max = false;
     boolean min;
     min = false;
     for (student studentArray1 : studentArray) {
     boolean gpa = false;

     }
 System.out.print("The highest GPA is: "+max);
 System.out.println();

 System.out.print("The lowest GPA is: "+min);
 System.out.println();


  System.out.println("Name: "+ studentArray[i].firstName + " "+ studentArray[i].lastName);

    System.out.println("Age: "+ studentArray[i].age);
     System.out.println("GPA: "+ studentArray[i].gpa);
 }
 }

public class student
 {
     //class variables
     public String firstName;
     public String lastName;
     public int age;
     public double gpa;
     public int max = 0;
     public int min = 0;


     //constructor method
     student(String a, String b, int c, double d)
     {
         firstName = a;
         lastName = b;
         age = c;
         gpa = d;

     }

     student(String a, String b, int c, double d, int e, int f)
     {
         firstName = a;
         lastName = b;
         age = c;
         gpa = d;
         min = e;
         max = f;

     }
     //a method that returns the student's complete name
     String getInfo()
     {
         return getFirstName() +" " + getLastName() +" " + getMax();

     }


     public String getFirstName()
     {
         return firstName;
     }



     public void setFirstName(String fn)
     {
         firstName = fn;
     }

     public String getLastName()
     {
         return lastName;
     }

     public void setLastName(String ln)
     {
         lastName = ln;
     }


     public int getAge()
     {
         return age;
     }


     public void setAge(int x)
     {
         age = x;
     }

     public double getGpa()
     {
         return gpa;
     }


     public void getGpa(double g)
     {
         gpa = g;
     }

     public int getMax()
     {
         return max;

     }
     public void getMax(int e)
     {
         max = e;
     }
     public int getMin()
     {
         return min;
     }
     public void getMin(int f)
     {
         min = f;

     }

 }
```

I would appreciate any insight that addresses the error and solutions for what I can do to make this code work properly.

Comment: Are you getting a compiler error? What command are you running and what is the exact error message?

Comment: The code you've posted won't compile; braces are mis-matched, there is no keyword `var` in Java. I don't see any file I/O or any place in your code that could produce the message "reached end of file while parsing"

Comment: If you add the 2 missing `}` at the end of the file, it wouldn't reach end-of-file while it was expecting more source code, i.e. while it was still in the middle of parsing!!!

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! The code you provided doesn't read from files, so the (presumably) exception cannot be thrown. Please check you've provided the correct code, and that your issue isn't with a different part of the application.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of (possible) issues with your posted code; you appear to be using an inner `student` class; your braces don't match up and your indentation doesn't seem to be consistent, and the `var` keyword doesn't exist in versions of Java prior to 10 (and we have no knowledge of your installed JDK or configured project compiler level). Your `student`(s) shouldn't have individual `min` and `max` fields.

There is some debate about the merits of a class with all `public` fields; but any possible advantage to that is negated when you also implement getters and setters for all of them.

You need two loops; one to find the `min` and `max`, one to display the `student`(s). Java naming conventions should be respected (class names start with a capital letter). And you have a `getGpa(double)` that should be a setter.

Fixing all of that, it might look something like

```
public class App {
    public static class Student {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private int age;
        private double gpa;

        public Student(String a, String b, int c, double d) {
            firstName = a;
            lastName = b;
            age = c;
            gpa = d;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fn) {
            firstName = fn;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String ln) {
            lastName = ln;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(int x) {
            age = x;
        }

        public double getGpa() {
            return gpa;
        }

        public void setGpa(double g) {
            gpa = g;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Student st1 = new Student("Rebecca", "Collins", 22, 3.3);
        Student st2 = new Student("Alex", "White", 19, 2.8);
        Student st3 = new Student("Jordan", "Anderson", 22, 3.1);
        Student[] studentArray = { st1, st2, st3 };
        Student maxStudent = studentArray[0];
        Student minStudent = studentArray[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < studentArray.length; i++) {
            if (studentArray[i].getGpa() > maxStudent.getGpa()) {
                maxStudent = studentArray[i];
            }
            if (studentArray[i].getGpa() < minStudent.getGpa()) {
                minStudent = studentArray[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("The highest GPA is: %.1f%n", maxStudent.getGpa());
        System.out.printf("The lowest GPA is: %.1f%n", minStudent.getGpa());
        for (Student s : studentArray) {
            System.out.printf("Name: %s %s%n", s.getFirstName(), s.getLastName());
            System.out.printf("Age: %d%n", s.getAge());
            System.out.printf("GPA: %.1f%n", s.getGpa());
        }
    }
}
```

which I ran; producing

```
The highest GPA is: 3.3
The lowest GPA is: 2.8
Name: Rebecca Collins
Age: 22
GPA: 3.3
Name: Alex White
Age: 19
GPA: 2.8
Name: Jordan Anderson
Age: 22
GPA: 3.1
```

**And**, if you're using Java 8+, you could simplify the `main` code with [`DoubleSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/DoubleSummaryStatistics.html) by streaming the `Student`(s), mapping to the gpa value and then collecting the statistics. Like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Student st1 = new Student("Rebecca", "Collins", 22, 3.3);
    Student st2 = new Student("Alex", "White", 19, 2.8);
    Student st3 = new Student("Jordan", "Anderson", 22, 3.1);
    Student[] studentArray = { st1, st2, st3 };
    DoubleSummaryStatistics dss = Arrays.stream(studentArray).mapToDouble(Student::getGpa).summaryStatistics();
    System.out.printf("The highest GPA is: %.1f%n", dss.getMax());
    System.out.printf("The lowest GPA is: %.1f%n", dss.getMin());
    Arrays.stream(studentArray).map(s -> String.format("Name: %s %s%nAge: %d%nGPA: %.1f", //
            s.getFirstName(), s.getLastName(), s.getAge(), s.getGpa())).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"the `var` keyword doesn't exist"*? It was added in Java 10 ([JEP 286: Local-Variable Type Inference](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286)), and extended to lambdas in Java 11 ([JEP 323: Local-Variable Syntax for Lambda Parameters](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/323)).

Comment: @Andreas Edited... prior to Java 10 and so on.